# Custom Class Framework/Structure

Tags: c#, class, structure

I am trying to get the following structure:

```
Game.Player.Position.setPos(X,Y,Z)
```

This is what framework I have so far:

```
public partial class Game
{
    public class Player
    {
        private class Position
        {
            public float setPos(float X, float Y, float Z)
            {
                //this code not included
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't exactly give me what I want. What I am trying to get is the following:

```
Player player1 = new Player();
player1.Position.setPos(player1_X, player1_Y, player1_Z);
```

However, whenever I declare player1- the only options I get are native ones (player1.Equals, player1.GetHashCode, player1.ToString, ect); Not player1.Position.setPos() or whatever.

I don't know what this is called- so if someone knows where I can get more information on this that would also help a bunch.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've declared your `Position` class ok, this is what described what a position is. What you're missing is a property on your `Player` class - ie saying that a `Player` can have a position:

```
public partial class Game
{
    public class Player
    {
        public class PositionClass
        {
            public float setPos(float X, float Y, float Z)
            {
                //this code not included
            }
        }

        public PositionClass Position {get; set;}

        public Player() {
            Position = new PositionClass();
        }
    }
}
```

Another thing is that you need to have the `Position` class as `Public`, as your property is going to expose it outside of the scope of the `Player` class.

Finally, you need to instantiate your `Position` property in your constructor so that you can call `setPos` directly after declaring a new `Player` as you've stated you want to.

Note: I've assumed a VS2010 Property Declaration for brevity. Also, I changed your `Position` class to be called `PositionClass`, just so you can see what's what in the example - you wouldn't normally do this, although you want to watch your namings so they aren't too confusing.

Comment: @ArpyClarkson don't forget to create the Position property ;)

Comment: Sorry, must have missed that when I commented.

Comment: Would I have to do the same concept with anything inside the PositionClass? like, how do I get the setPos to show up when I do say player1.Position.setPos?